# Automapper Dictionary Properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to use AutoMapper to map between a class that has a dictionary property and I'm not sure how to proceed.

This is a simple representation of the classes on both sides of the map

```
public class Person {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string, Post> Posts {get;set;}
}

public class Post {
    public string PostName {get;set;}
}
```

Creating the map as follow:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Api.Entities.Person, App.Entities.Person>();
```

Results in the error:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>   Mapping types:
>
> Post -> Post
>   Api.Entities.Post -> App.Entities.Post
>
> Destination path: Person.Posts.Posts.Posts0[0]
>   Source value: Api.Entities.Post

Comment: The map you created is wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I have an Api.Entities.Person object which i want to map to App.Entities.Person. If i comment out the Dictionary Post it works. If i include it, it fails with the above error

Comment: Implement a custom value resolver and add your own logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create also a mapper for the Post entity. Basically, the error is saying that you are using Post inside Person, but couldn't find a way to map that Post property.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Api.Entities.Post, App.Entities.Post>();
```